# Setting value from one class to another in Java

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jcombobox

I have got three Java classes:

- The First has a setter and a getter
- The Second has a JComboBox
- The third has a MySQL query and generating list.

I used the setter to set the value and I set the value from the combo box class.

Now, I would like to get this value in another class.

Here is my code:

```
public class Settings {

    private static String RootName;

    public static void setRootName(String rootName){
     RootName = rootName;
    }

    public static String getRootName(){
     return RootName;
    }
}
```

combobox.java

```
public class ComboBoxDemo extends JPanel
                          implements ActionListener {
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Trainpis";
    JLabel picture;
    public static String i="hello";
public String rootname;
    public ComboBoxDemo()  {

 JComboBox combo=new JComboBox();
combo.addActionListener(this);



JFrame f=new JFrame();
JPanel p=new JPanel();
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select route from route");
while(rs.next()){
combo.addItem(rs.getString("route"));
//System.out.println(rs.getString("route"));
}
}
catch(Exception e){}
p.add(combo);
f.add(p);
  f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
  f.setUndecorated(true);
f.setVisible(true);

 }

    /** Listens to the combo box. */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String selectedRoute = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
       // System.out.println(rootname);
        String root1="Huda City Center - Noida City Center";
       if(selectedRoute.equalsIgnoreCase(root1))
       {
           System.out.println("hello");
     //new Test();
           //Settings mysettings = new Settings();
   Settings.setRootName(selectedRoute);

    RootSelection1 r1 = new RootSelection1();
        r1.print();
       }
       else{
       System.out.println("bye");
       } 
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ComboBoxDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the selected value of combo box:

```
String rootSelection = Settings.getRootName();
String selectStoredProc = "SELECT sino,stationname,distance from station where route ='"+rootSelection+"'";
String [] root;

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(selectStoredProc);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        String s1=rs.getString("stationname"); 
        nameList.add(s1);
        root = nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

I want to do all of this on combo box's selected item.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please and what it should do, whats goal

Comment: it should pass value combobox selected item in to third class

Comment: Just a tip, I would be careful of `"SELECT sino,stationname,distance from station where route ='"+rootSelection+"'";` this can be dangerous for security (injection).

Comment: Can you provide the source where you create the Combobox and stuff? Because (beside its quite horrible when it comes to good code) with that static stuff you do there and above snippeds the value will be available in the third snipped... e.g. you already do what you ask for by String rootSelection = Settings.getRootName(); which makes me guess you just dont get back anything from your query? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second class create a `Settings` object

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    String selectedRoute = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
    RootSelection r1=new RootSelection();

    //Settings object
    Settings mySettings = new Settings();
    mySettings.setRootName(selectedRoute);
}
```

Then pass this object to your method in your third class

A side note:

you shouldn't make your `Settings` class full of static things

E.g. This is better

```
public class Settings {

    private String RootName;

    public void setRootName(String rootName){
     RootName = rootName;
    }

    public String getRootName(){
     return RootName;
    }
}
```

Comment: i did as u mentioned but  Here   Settings.setRootName(selectedRoute); giving error

Comment: @user3419449 Wait a sec there, Settings.setRootName(selectedRoute) tries to access a static member method whereas settings.setRootName(selectedRoute) is what you should have wrote.

Comment: I guess he thinks he still can use your "better" (private String RootName...) class like before, e.g. "Settings.setRootName(..."

Comment: I have updated the answer, changed object name from _settings_ to _mySettings_

Comment: errr is  non static method setRootName(String) can not be refrrenced from a static context

Comment: how it will be use in third class

Comment: @Conan youre right but i guess you will make him bigger troubles than he has right now... it seems he doesnt understand the difference between dyn/ static so he wont be able to hand the reference from class2 to class3;D

Comment: @user3419449 you can paste in your entire 3 classes then we can support you better ;)

Comment: `public void yourMethodName (... Settings mySettings) {   String passedIn = mySettings.getRootName();   }` I'm just assuming your method return type is void here.

Comment: i ma using constructer

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are class levels. So You are changing the fist class static variable in second calls. So you can access the first class variable in third class. You can get by using 
Settings.getRootName(); in your third class

Comment: which is what he does with String rootSelection = Settings.getRootName(); as faar as i understand it ;)